# how to avoid the exception when nothing is entered in edittext?

Tags: android, exception, android-edittext

I have created edittexts in which user can enter numbers. In my app user can submit the values by clicking on submit button.(Note: Initially I set all 3 EditTexts to "" with setText() in the code)After submitting I have kept these following lines to retrieve values in the method.

```
String st1=editText1.getText().toString();
int tempVal1=Integer.parseInt(st);
String st2=editText2.getText().toString();
int tempVa2=Integer.parseInt(st);
String st3=editText2.getText().toString();
int tempVal3=Integer.parseInt(st);
```

But here my problem is if the user doesn't enter any value in the first editText and fills only 2nd and 3rd and submits, then the value in the tempVal1 should be 0. But I am getting exception becuase of the first statement because of not having any data. How to avoid this exception and keep the tempVal 0 when he doesn't fill anything in the respective edittext?

I have one more doubt, when I add this  `int x=Integer.valueOf(editText.getText());` line, I am getting the following error. Why?`The method valueOf(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Editable)`

Please clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check the `EditText` before converting it into Number.

```
if( !editText1.getText().toString().equals("") && editText1.getText().toString().length() > 0 )
{
    // Get String
    Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the condition for edit text is not null or there is no value in edit text like below.

Condition for EditText is not Blank.

```
if(editText1.getText().toString().length() != 0)
{
    // Get String
    Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: There's a way with fewer conversions: `TextUtils.isEmpty(editText1.getText())` returns true if the string is  null or 0-length.

Answer (score 0):

> The method valueOf(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for
>   the arguments (Editable)

means it is looking for a String argument but gets an `Editable`

try `x=Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());`

And about the Exception :

Surround your code with `Try & Catch` , or do Null checks before you parse integers.

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting NumberFormatException, as String is blank, and blank cant be parsed into integer.
So, initialize these variables with 0. and put parsing code into try catch. as below:

```
int tempVal1=0;
int tempVal2=0;
int tempVal3=0;

String st1=editText1.getText().toString();
try{    
  tempVal1=Integer.parseInt(st1);
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex) {}

String st2=editText2.getText().toString();
try{
   tempVal2=Integer.parseInt(st2);
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex){}

String st3=editText2.getText().toString();
try{    
   tempVal3=Integer.parseInt(st3);
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex){}
```

Comment: First answer that takes care of more mistakes, not just empty edit box.. However: you don't need to assign anything in the `catch` block, as variables are all already equal 0 (and it won't change if we fall into `catch`), and also - a note for op - silently changing user input (effectively) might not be best idea. At least pop some error box stating that not entered value is 0 by default (or let him know some other way)

Comment: yes, we can remove these statements in catch block, I have made the changes.

Comment: I also edited your aswer, for you had typos in variables names, and I changed formatting a  little bit... Btw if you add your explanation for the second part of the question (about editable), I think your answer would be full and eligible for being accepted...

Comment: Thanks for the edition, but is NumberFormatException is itself not self-explainatory.

Comment: This is not a proper way of coding.. Why to catch an exception which you are sure is bound to happen. Instead avoid it using necessary checks. TextUtils.isEmpty(editText1.getText()) seems to be the most easy way to check it.

Comment: @VickyKapadia and how do you know user won't insert text into editbox or a float number? Or maybe not simply insert but paste, and application didn't catch it (so didn't remove letters)? I agree that if we are 100% sure there won't be text, we should avoid catching exceptions.. Now I see only numbers are allowed in the editBox, I didn't read the question thoroughly, I admit, my bad..
P.S the exception isn't bound to happen ;) If correct number is inserted ;)

Comment: If Try Catch is not suitable here, than I dont think, there is a situation, where this exception must be caught.

Comment: In fact the complete solution will be to use this: If(!TextUtils.isEmpty(str) && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(str)). It will make sure what you are parsing is a number only..But catching an exception to solve the problem is definitely not a good idea..